# Missing "&" and commas in in-text citations in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bibliography, citations

My pdf output does not show APA in-text citation properly.

This is my YAML

```
---
title: "A fancy project"
author: "A reliable human being"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex  
    citation_package: biblatex         
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{arabluatex}
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Lateef}
date: "2022-09-16"
bibliography: references.bib
csl: apa.csl
biblatexoptions:
  - citestyle = authoryear
  - bibstyle = authoryear
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``

# Rmarkdown

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [@al2020الخصائص] consectetur.


# Reference
```

reference.bib

```
@article{al2020الخصائص,
  title={\txarb{الخصائص السيكو مترية للصورة العربية للإصدار الثاني من قائمة الخمسة الكبار}},
  author={Al-Ansari, Bader M and Alali, Talal B},
  journal={BAU Journal-Society, Culture and Human Behavior},
  volume={1},
  number={2},
  pages={3},
  year={2020}
}
```

[image]

Note that the "&" character is not used and commas are missing. Instead of

> (Al-Ansari and Alali 2020)

it should be

> (Al-Ansari & Alali, 2020)

The problem persists in the references as well where "&" should be used.

Comment: Can you simplify your example at all?  I don't have Arabic fonts or packages installed, so I can't process it.  If you have a minimal example without all of that, does it still illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set biblatex style option as `apa`, and you do not have to specify `csl: apa`.

````
---
title: "A fancy project"
author: "A reliable human being"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex  
    citation_package: biblatex         
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{arabluatex}
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Lateef}
date: "2022-09-16"
bibliography: references.bib
biblatexoptions:
  - style = apa
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Rmarkdown

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [@al2020الخصائص] consectetur.


# Reference
````

---

[image: Apa style in Arabic references with biblatex]

---